# reverse the 3 digit number in python

Tags: python, numbers, reverse

you can see my code in below. I got error that in that line **"print(str(values))"**
it says

> Unindent doesn't match any outer indentation level.

What is wrong with it?

```
values = ''
def reverse(numbers):
    print('please enter a 3 digit number :')
    number = input()
    if 100 > number:
        print('the number is not 3 digit')

    values[0] == number[2]
    values[1] == number[1]
    values[2] == number[0]
    print(str(values))


 print(reverse(135))
```

Comment: You have an extra space on that line. Tap your backspace key once

Answer (score 0):

Check the print line, you've extra space before print command. After that a better way to reverse strings or numbers is using the [list comprehention](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) (you should convert your number to string first), you can make something like this:

```
my_value = '123' # or str(my_value)[::-1]
print my_value[::-1] # This result is 321
```

Note: Your if block haven't any effect, because you print the message but in the next line you proceed with operation. In this case I think that your operation should be in a else block.

Answer (score -2):

This is a program to reverse a 3 digit number.

```py
l=list(input("please enter a 3 digit no.="))
print(l[2],l[1],l[0])
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please prefer answering the specific question asked over suggesting/stating alternative answers, in this case explaining what's wrong with the asker's code instead of providing another piece of code that works.